# Combine values of two dynamic keys in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
const query = {
  item: {
    'available': false
  },
  status: {
    'locked': true
  }
}
```

I want to fetch the nested keys `available` and `locked` and create a new object with their values, resulting in

```js
{
  'available': false,
  'locked': true
}
```

Whats the most precise way to do this? Bear in mind that the keys and the nested keys are dynamic, i.e. can change in future depending on another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values and create a new object.

```js
const
    query = { item: { available: false }, status: { locked: true } },
    joined = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(query));

console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator:

```js
const query = {
  item: {
    'available': false
  },
  status: {
    'locked': true
  }
}

const value = {...query.item, ...query.status};

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).